# How do I open an included java class(for example JButton) in IntelliJ IDEA 10?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I want to be able to open up the JButton class and see the code inside it. The reason is because I want to override one of the methods, but I want to make sure I include all the functionality that that method normally has. Also, it'd be a good way to learn. I know I can do it when I've had errors by clicking on the class in the error messages. But any ideas on how to bring it up normally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Go To | Class** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>), type JButton (Include non-project classes checkbox will be enabled automatically if no such classes are found in your project).

If you already have `JButton` usage in your code, you can navigate to its source using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> while the caret is on it.

Of course you need sources attached to the JSDK, but it should be fine by default (as JSDK installation has sources on most platforms). If you are on Mac, you will have to download them separately and attach to the JSDK configuration in **File | Project Structure | SDKs**.

Comment: But Why should you use Ctrl+N instead of Ctrl +B ?

Comment: If you don't have JButton referenced anywhere in your code yet, you can't use Ctrl+B, otherwise it's fine to use F4/Ctrl+B to navigate to the source from the usage.

Comment: Related to reason of question : "The reason is because I want to override one of the methods," I think reference is present :)

Comment: OK, I've updated my reply. However sometimes it's faster to press Ctrl+N and type rather then navigate to the word using keyboard arrows or even search and then press Ctrl+B. Moving away to mouse would be even slower. IDEA is keyboard oriented and I think that my suggestion is faster in most cases.

Comment: I am using your suggestion just to look at some classes like implementation of classes and so on, but if I need to look at something in dev mode, I mean like extending button and so on better, just for me, it is Ctrl+B.

Answer (score 1):

If you have sources just press `Ctrl+B` on `JButton`, if you have no, download sources, add to configuration of project and press the same combination

Answer (score 0):

Download the Java Source code here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Also don't forget about the `super` keyword which you can use to interact with the extended class

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the Java source code.  If you're using Java 1.6, for example, you can [go here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) to get it.  Unzip it somewhere on your local disk.

When I need to look at the source code of a Java class I then navigate to the source class and drag it into my IDE.

If you want to ensure you get all the functionality of the original method, call the original method as part of your method.  Using `super` gives you a reference to the overridden method, e.g. `super.overridden();`.  Don't just copy the Java source into your method.